Slackware - automatically update all packages
That's the interface I want. I click a checkbox (or edit a line in a config file) and all packages in the distribution are checked for updates periodically (may be every week) and all these updates are automatically installed.
How to set it up?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
